# How to close the connection with vault?

Tags: go, hashicorp-vault

I need to create a new client , write secrets and then i need to close the connection with vault properly. 
I am able to open new client using using golang but not able to close it.

Comment: Please provide more details, post your code ([mcve]), and also what problems / errors you get.

Comment: This is very unusal. Why do you want to close the connections? Anyway, the [Config](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/vault/api#Config) has a HttpClient field that you can use to [close idle connections](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client.CloseIdleConnections).

Comment: Okay. thx. So it is just HTTP connection close.

Comment: You don't even need to explicitly close the idle HTTP connections. There is no reason to.